# Rust разрыв соедениния с websoket

Tags: rust, ping, websokets

День добрый. Понемногу переношу свои питоновские скрипты на **Rust**, один из них вывод ликвидаций монет из веб сокета. Проблема скорее всего несущественная, однако не понимаю как решить. Код в принципе работает(При условии если в течении 2х минут сокет отдаст порцию данных), однако если будет тишина, а это нормально, ликвидации позиций трейдеров не каждую секунду происходят, то скрипт через 2 минуты разрывает соединение.

```
use serde_json;
use tungstenite::connect;
use url::Url;

static BINANCE_WS: &str = "wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/btcusdt";

fn main() {
    let api_request = ["@forceOrder"];

    let binance_url = format!("{}{}", BINANCE_WS, api_request[0]);

    let (mut socket, response) =
        connect(Url::parse(&binance_url).unwrap()).expect("Can't connect...");

    println!("Connected to binance stream.");
    println!("HTTP status code: {}", response.status());
    println!("Response headers:");

    for (ref header, ref header_value) in response.headers() {
        println!("- {}: {:?}", header, header_value);
    }

    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message...");

        let msg = match msg {
            tungstenite::Message::Text(s) => s,
            _ => {
                panic!("Error getting text...");
            }
        };

        let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Unable to parse msg...");

        println!(
            "Coin[{}] == Side[{}] == Price[{}] == Count[{}] ",
            parsed["o"]["s"], parsed["o"]["S"], parsed["o"]["p"], parsed["o"]["q"]
        );
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Connected to binance stream.
HTTP status code: 101 Switching Protocols
Response headers:
- date: "Sat, 05 Nov 2022 10:31:46 GMT"
- connection: "upgrade"
- upgrade: "websocket"
- sec-websocket-accept: "NFDEuqtSsdgP56Rh0jIqNkGkfxk="
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error getting text...', src/main.rs:42:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

В общем удалось понять из-за чего падает коннект, между json ответами сервер шлет **Ping([],)** Правда я не могу сообразить как это в приделах **match** обработать, в **tungstenite** есть **tungstenite::Message::Ping\Pong** но что-то мне это не сильно помогает ))

Comment: Так у вас паника возникает в `match msg`, т.е. в msg пришёл какой-то другой вариант, а не `Text`. Вам нужно посмотреть, что приходит и как-то обработать без panic.

Comment: Да я понимал что паник в match происходит, я проверю что там прилетает, спасибо за наводку. Просто я не перепроверив, сделал вывод что, разрыв происходит просто из-за того, что нет потока данных и коннект разрывается по таймауту например.

Comment: Проверил через вывод msg без исключений, Происходит следующие, дисконекта больше нет, на бирже происходит ликвидация позиций, в сокет прилетает запись кого выкинуло, и после этой записи добавляется лишний Enter, и я сейчас не про поведение функции println!, после нее, каретка повторно переводиться на новую строку, возможно, некий пустой ответ приходит и это выбивает на паник.... Но что-то кроме json строки ничего не выводиться. кроме лишнего перевода на новую строку. На протяжении всего коннекта, если нет json, каретка делает новый переход на строку и так пару раз до нового json ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации к [write_message](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/protocol/struct.WebSocket.html#method.write_message), `tungstenite-rs` автоматически отвечает на `Ping` сообщения. Так что отдельно обрабатывать их не требуется.

Если нужно обрабатывать только сообщения с `Text`, то код можно поменять на

```
loop {
    let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message...");

    if let tungstenite::Message::Text(msg) = msg {
        let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Unable to parse msg...");

        println!(
            "Coin[{}] == Side[{}] == Price[{}] == Count[{}] ",
            parsed["o"]["s"], parsed["o"]["S"], parsed["o"]["p"], parsed["o"]["q"]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Примного благодарен, один из моих минусов ))) не мешало бы почаще документацию читать ))